# MySQL Группировка по одному типу

Tags: mysql

Добрый день!
Есть таблица активностей id, type, source_id;
В ней есть типы type: Image, Progress, Program, Profile
Нужно составить запрос таким образом, чтобы группировка шла только по одному типу Image, а остальные Progress, Program, Profile не группировались. Т.е. есть:

```
source_id   type
     1      Image
     2      Image
     3      Image
     4      Program
     5      Profile
     6      Program
     7      Profile
```

Нужно получить:

```
    source_id     type    source_ids
       1          Image     1,2,3
       4          Program   4
       5          Profile   5
       6          Program   6
       7          Profile   7
```

Спасибо!

Comment: А UNION подойдет?

    SELECT *, GROUP_CONCAT(source_id) AS source_ids
    FROM table_name WHERE type = 'Image'
    
    UNION
    
    SELECT *, source_id AS source_ids
    FROM table_name WHERE type <> 'Image';

Comment: В принципе, тоже вариант. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
    *,
    CASE
        WHEN
            (`user_activity`.`type` = 'AddImage')
        THEN
            GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT `user_activity`.`source_id`
                ORDER BY `user_activity`.`created_at` ASC
                SEPARATOR ', ')
        ELSE `user_activity`.`id`
    END ids
FROM
    `user_activity`
GROUP BY type , CASE
    WHEN (type = 'AddImage') THEN `user_activity`.`user_id`
    ELSE `user_activity`.`id`
END
```